# Pandas display DataFrame without wrapping columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use pandas to display data in a table format and for some reason, my last column is running off and being placed under the table instead of being on the far right of the table. I drew a picture of what the output ends up looking like. It also has a '\' right before the last column name for some reason. Is my table just too long horizontally? Any help is appreciated!

[image]

here's the code for this ('data' is a tuple w/ 8 elements):

```
pandas.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pandas.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

df = pandas.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5', 'Col6', 'Col7', 'Col8'])

print(df)
```

Comment: That "\" means continuation, if you do it on a jupyter notebook / google colab you might see a scroll bar that allows you to move horizontally.

Comment: It's right. Your table is too long. That's why you have a '\' at the end.

Comment: @CeliusStingher oh okay I gotchya, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Corralien thanks, I was hoping that wasn't the case but it is what it is haha

Comment: If it's a single column out of frame, you can try reducing the font size of the output, perhaps that helps you get it in a single box with no need for continuation

Comment: Please don't edit "SOLVED" into the title - accept the answer.

Answer (score 6):

see the pandas docs on [options and settings](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html).

You should be setting `display.width` not `display.max_columns`. From the docs:

`display.max_columns` (default 0 or 20):

> max_rows and max_columns are used in **repr**() methods to decide if to_string() or info() is used to render an object to a string. In case Python/IPython is running in a terminal this is set to 0 by default and pandas will correctly auto-detect the width of the terminal and switch to a smaller format in case all columns would not fit vertically. The IPython notebook, IPython qtconsole, or IDLE do not run in a terminal and hence it is not possible to do correct auto-detection, in which case the default is set to 20. ‘None’ value means unlimited.

`display.width` (default 80):

> Width of the display in characters. In case Python/IPython is running in a terminal this can be set to None and pandas will correctly auto-detect the width. Note that the IPython notebook, IPython qtconsole, or IDLE do not run in a terminal and hence it is not possible to correctly detect the width.

`display.max_columns` sets the *total* number of columns to display, which includes wrapped columns. `display.width` tells pandas how many columns/characters to use when displaying each row of a dataframe's repr.

Note that this is purely a discussion of the display - the data itself is not being placed at the bottom of the table.

Comment: thank you! Editing the width allowed everything to fit how I wanted it to!

Comment: glad it helped! rather than changing the question name to [solved], on stack overflow the convention is to select the correct answer. check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). welcome!